# No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)

Tags: scala, log4j, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to connect Apache Kafka to Apache Flink by creating a Kafka Consumer in Scala. This is my Consumer code:

```
val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val stream = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09[String]("test", new  SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
            .print
env.enableCheckpointing(5000)
```

When I run this program I get some warnings from log4j and the program terminates, no output is shown. My Kafka Producer is up and running.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Are you running this from an IDE or on an external Flink installation. In case of an external installation, did you check the log files of the job manager and task manager? Flink stream programs print to the `./log/*out` files of the task managers.

Comment: @FabianHueske no log files are getting created. I am running this from Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the log4j WARN is the reason for the program termination.
Those issues usually occur when log4j is not available in the classpath.

The reason why no output is produced is because the `env.execute()` call is missing, so the job is never started.

Comment: Worked! Can you tell me how to add log4j in classpath?

Comment: My answer is actually inaccurate: The problem with log4j is that there is most likely no configuration file in your classpath.
To fix that, add a resources folder, and put a `log4j.properties` file in their (make sure your IDE recognizes the folder properly and adds the file to the classpath). You can use this file as a reference: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-0.8/src/test/resources/log4j-test.properties